# How to output only the string in list data?

Tags: python, string, list, split, append

My file reads the teamNames.txt file which is:

```
Collingwood

Essendon

Hawthorn

Richmond
```

Code:

```
file2 = input("Enter the team-names file: ") ## E.g. teamNames.txt

bob = open(file2)
teamname = []

for line1 in bob: ##loop statement until no more line in file
    teamname.append(line1)

print(teamname)
```

The output is:

```
['Collingwood\n', 'Essendon\n', 'Hawthorn\n', 'Richmond\n']
```

I want to make it so the output will be:

```
Collingwood, Essendon, Hawthorn, Richmond
```

Comment: When you are appending the `line1` to `teamname` just `strip` the `line1` before that by using `teamname.append(line1.strip())`. And inside print, convert your list to a string by using `print(“, “.join(teamname))`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the `replace()` function. I've modified your code to include this function.

```
file2= input("Enter the team-names file: ") ## E.g. teamNames.txt

bob =open(file2)
teamname = []

for line1 in bob: ##loop statement until no more line in file
    teamname.append(line1.replace("\n",""))

print(teamname)
```

Would give you the output:

```
['Collingwood', 'Essendon', 'Hawthorn', 'Richmond']
```

You could then modify `teamname` to get your requested output:

```
print(", ".join(teamname))
```

Comment: thanks alot!, i never considered the replace() function

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
for line1 in bob:
    teamname.append(line1.strip()) # .strip() removes the \n

print (', '.join(teamname))
```

The `.join()` does the final formatting.

---

**Update.** I now think a more pythonistic (and elegant) answer would be:

```
file2 = input("Enter the team-names file: ") ## E.g. teamNames.txt

with open(file2) as f:
    teamname = [line.strip() for line in f]

print (', '.join(teamname))
```

The `with` statement ensures the file is closed when the block finishes. Instead of doing the `for` loop, it now uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), a cool way to create a list by transforming the elements from another list (or from an [iterable object](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator), like `file`).

Comment: thanks alot! i know this question was very simple, and i used split but did it like teamname = teamname.split() which gave an error.

Answer (score -2):

The join method works well but you can also try using a for loop.

```
for name in teamname: # takes each entry separately 
    print name
```